# How to run python script inside my Azure Linux VM with Azure automation runbooks

Tags: linux, azure, automation

I would like to know how to run a python script in a Linux Azure VM with Azure Automation Runbook

Comment: Have you tried to use Hybrid Runbook Worker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-linux-hrw-install/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?